# how to save/load pandas dataframe that contain non-ordered dictonary as field without knowing possible key name and value type to/from parquet?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

In our application, we need to append segments of dataframe to parquet storage.
However the following code will fail at the load time, due to unmatched type

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [{'k1': 0, 'k2':1}, {'k3': 'ok'}]})
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, None], 'b': [{'k1': None}, {'k3': None}]})
pq_dir = "/tmp/test.pq"
for _df in [df_test1, df_test2]:
    pa_data = pa.Table.from_pandas(_df)
    display(pa_data)
    pq.write_to_dataset(pa_data,root_path=pq_dir)
pd.read_parquet(pq_dir)
```

The reason is the df_test1 will be convert to a table:

```
pyarrow.Table
a: double
b: struct<k1: int64, k2: int64, k3: string>
  child 0, k1: int64
  child 1, k2: int64
  child 2, k3: string
```

the df_test2 will be onvert to another kind of schema:

```
pyarrow.Table
a: double
b: struct<k1: null, k3: null>
  child 0, k1: null
  child 1, k3: null
```

one would suggest to make our own schema to match all b value, however, this is impossible, we do not have much constrain on that except the key must be string. the value can be string, int, float, list, etc.

I wonder, how can we deal with this kind of problem?

one solution is:

```
pd.concat(d.to_table().to_pandas() for d in pa.dataset.dataset(pq_dir).get_fragments())
```

But if I do this I cannot use feature like read from row N to row M, I have to read in the entire dataset, which is unlikely to happen for very big ones.

another way is to dump the dict to json, however, this wastes lots of memory, since the json is not very efficient.

fastparquet can do this easily

```
import fastparquet
df_test1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1., 2], 'b': [{'k1': 0, 'k2':1}, {'k3': 'ok'}]})
df_test2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1., None], 'b': [{'k1': None}, {'k3': None}]})
pq_dir = "/tmp/test1.pq"

for _i, _df in enumerate([df_test1, df_test2]):
    fastparquet.write(pq_dir, _df, file_scheme="hive", append=_i>0)
fastparquet.ParquetFile(pq_dir).to_pandas()
```

But their code quality still looks too young, sigh.
I looked into the detail:
pyarrow actually save the data into 4 columns: a, b.k1, b.k2, b.k3. that is why it cannot handle the dictionary data very well.
In other hand fastparquet did a nasty trick in behind.
It automatically convert the dict object to a plain text json:

```
<pyarrow._parquet.ParquetSchema object at 0x7f6f80d9fd00>
required group field_id=-1 schema {
  optional double field_id=-1 a;
  optional binary field_id=-1 b (JSON);
}
```

We can see the string like this:

```
pqt = pq.read_table('/tmp/test1.pq')
pqt[1][1].as_py().decode()
# '{"k3":"ok"}'
```

So though it sees fastpqrquet can handle this, but it actually handle it in an very inefficient way.

If I were in their position, I probably will at least try to use jsonb or bson.

IN summary, It expect the data have fixed schema (relationship data model), though the parquet in general actually support shcema evolution.
More weird thing is in [R api](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/concat_tables.html) there is `unify_schema=True` in concat_table, in pyarrow this option did not correctly exposed.
So it seems the pyarrow is somehow incomplete.

It cannot handle dict in cell or array in cell very well just like most sql-like database.

so maybe any one data require a bit non-relationship data model, pyarrow is not a goo choice here?

Comment: Perhaps `concat` the dataframes first and then convert the entire dataset into a table?

Comment: not really doable, we have continuous data flow. it can last weeks. 1. it may not fit into RAM. 2. we want to write to disk imediately

Comment: pyarrow can try to "unify" table schemas, but it doesn't work for nested fields (struct). If you call `flatten()` on your tables before saving them it should work. It's possible that this will be handled better in future version.